# Rotation of text and Image

Tags: codenameone

I want to make rotation of text and image. Is this possible with Codename one? If yes please let me know how it's done with code with sample lines of code.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are trying to do. There are basically two ways:

1. Draw everything on a square mutable image and use the method rotate to get a rotated version.
2. If you are targeting iOS/Android you can use the rotate affine transform on the `Graphics` class while drawing and invoke `resetAffine()` when finished.